# How to properly call methods and functions removing the need for static

Tags: php

I watched a course on OOP PDO a few months ago it was built using static and non static with autoload class maps,

but after some time reading and searching on stack overflow and this site here [static methods](https://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice)

I decided to learn about namespaces and PSR4, I am not using a MVC as of yet but just trying to get my ducks in a row.

The included navbar used a static method to show or hide links based on a static method

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div class="navi">
        <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>">Home</a>
        <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>/About</a>
        <a href="#">Community</a>
        <?php if (Auth::isLoggedIn()) : ?>
            <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>/account">Account</a>
            <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>/logout">Logout</a>           
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>/registration">Signup</a>
            <a href="<?= APP_URL ?>/login">Login</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The static method require_login

```
    public static function require_login(): void
    {
        if (!static::isLoggedIn()) {
            Helpers::redirect(Paths::HOME);
        }
    }
```

```
public function isLoggedIn(): bool
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_logged_in']);
}
```

Both i have put in a class called Auth

I change `require_login` to `public function`

Then I changed

`if (!static::isLoggedIn()) {`

to

```
if (!$this->isLoggedIn()) {
```

In my navigation I added

```
use App\Auth\Auth
```

Then changed the navigation code to

```
<?php if ((new Auth)->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
```

my question is `(new Auth)->isLoggedIn()` is this a acceptable way to write or call? I have not found any information on this.

Comment: "bad" in what sense? That's a pretty vague term. If you need to create a new instance of the object there, then create one. If you have an existing instance, maybe it would make sense to use that...we don't know though, we've got no context. We don't even know for sure if making it instance-based instead of static was a good thing in your scenario.

Comment: and if you also look at that function body (isLoggedIn) it doesn't rely on any instance data.. so making it an instance method doesn't add anything to the game. The static method can be called just referencing the class (instead of the object) and it already relies on a global variable ($_SESSION) that don't need an object instance to be scoped in isolation

Comment: @DiegoD ok but lets say you need a instance  let's say user would $user = (new User)->signUp();  be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, That's totally acceptable in php, in a more convenient way, we could write: (new User())->signUp(); cause in some cases we will have to pass arguments to the constructor